# maxima substpart without knowing position

Tags: substitution, maxima

If I want to replace a part of an expression, I can use `substpart`. But I need to know the position of the part in the expression, given by its position in the part

Now I have as example:

```
$$\int_{0}^{a}{\left. {{\% e}^{-(a+b^2) x}}dx\right.}$$
```

I can find for the part `$(a+b^2)$` with the part command an expression with a number
i.e. `(%t65)`, but there is not given the position numbers in the tree.
Is there a possibility to replace this expression by another expression, i.e. `(%o45)` by some command like `substpart(%o45,expr, **%t65**)`  without determining the position?

Thanks

Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to substitute `whatever` for `a` in `expr`, you can say: `subst(a = whatever, expr)` which substitutes for `a` in any and every position.

I don't recommend `part` and similar functions. It is very brittle in the sense that a minor change in the expression will make it stop working.